# Floer's space closed under products? 

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Floer (in "The unregularized gradient flow of the symplectic action") 
defined a dense subspace of $C^\infty$ with the structure of a Banach space,
with norm $\Vert f \Vert = \sum_{k \ge 0} \epsilon_k \Vert  f \Vert_{C^k}$
for some constants $\epsilon_k$.

Question:  How do the constants $\epsilon_k$ in Floer's
norm behave as $k \to \infty$?  He just shows that some constants exist for which
the resulting space is dense in $C^\infty$.  Do the constants go to infinity,
to zero, or neither?

Subquestion:  Is Floer's space closed under products of functions?

Comment: In case $\epsilon_k\sim (k!)^s$ this essentially gives Gevrey classes, see my other answer. More general (log-convex) sequences give rise to the so called Mandelbrojt classes. Not that Mandelbrojt, an older one.

Comment: er.. I mean $\epsilon_k \sim (k!)^{-s}$

Answer (score 2):

Floer chooses $\epsilon_k$ so that this $\epsilon$ space is dense in $L^2$ (this should be equivalent to dense in $C^\infty$, since the latter is dense in $L^2$, and Floer's $\epsilon$ space sits in $C^\infty$).

To show that this subspace is dense in $L^2$, it suffices to show that one can approximate
indicator functions.
For this, he needs the $\epsilon_k$ to go to zero very fast.  His explicit
construction in Lemma 5.1 (of the "unregularized gradient flow" paper) is to take a fixed cut-off function $\beta$,
and approximate the characteristic function of a rectangle.  The
approximation to a characteristic function is going to be a product of
terms that behave like $\beta(x/\delta)$ (with a better approximation
as $\delta \rightarrow 0$).  Thus, the behaviour of the
$\epsilon$-norm is going to be roughly:
\[
\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \epsilon_k \delta^{-k} a_k,
\]
where $a_k = \sup | D^k \beta |$.  We need this to converge for each $\delta > 0$.
Floer takes $\epsilon_k = (a_k k^k)^{-1}$.  In particular, then, these constants are going to
$0$.  Following this argument, it seems we can take the $\epsilon_k$ to be on the order of $1/k!$.

Note that if the sequence $\epsilon_k$ is not summable, we expect the
space to be very small.  In particular, consider this norm on a
compact interval, say $[-\pi, \pi]$.  Then, cos(x) is not in the
space.

The Floer $\epsilon$ space forms a Banach algebra if $\epsilon_k$ decays faster than $1/k!$.
Then, 
\[
\sum \epsilon_k |D^{(k)}(fg)|
 \le  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^{k}
 \epsilon_k | D^{(l)} f|
 |D^{(k-l)} g | \binom{k}{l}
= \sum_{l=0}^\infty  |D^{(l)} f| \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \binom{l+p}{p} \epsilon_{p+l} | D^{(p)}g|
\]
When $\epsilon_{p+l} \binom{l+p}{p}
 \le \epsilon_p \epsilon_l$, we are then in business.
In particular, this works for Floer's original construction.

Comment: Sam, do you have a lower bound on $a_k$?

Comment: If we follow Floer's definition of the cut-off functions, we can crudely bound them below by 1.  To recall, Floer's definition is that $\beta : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\beta(x) = 0$ near $0$ and $\beta(x) = 1$ near 1, $\beta'(x) \ge 0$.  He then uses products of functions of the form $\beta(|x-y|/\delta)$ to approximate characteristic functions of rectangles.  

Actually, we might be able to do better and get something like $1/d^k$, where d is the diameter of the support of $\beta$.  (The exact bound doesn't really matter because of the $1/\delta^k$ term that shows up.)

Comment: Ah yes - by the mean-value theorem and induction. (For the uniform lower bound, I mean.)  Missed that. Thanks!